# Docker - max depth exceeded

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So I am using this example:

https://github.com/mcmoe/mssqldocker

In order to create a SQL Server image and load it with data.  I have several sql scripts which I run when I run the container.

However, I started getting this error when building the image:

```
Step 7/9 : ENTRYPOINT ./entrypoint.sh
 ---> Running in c8c654f6a630
max depth exceeded
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, I restarted docker and even updated it.
I read something about 125 layers?  Can anyone explain the cause of this and a potential fix?

I found this command to run:

```
docker history microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest | wc -l
 312
```

My docker-compose yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mssql:
      build: .
      image: 'microsoft/mssql-server-linux'
      ports:
          - '1433:1433'
      environment:
          - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
          - SA_PASSWORD=Abcgfgh123!
      volumes:
          - db_volume:/var/lib/mssql/data
volumes:
  db_volume:
```

Comment: `docker history microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest |  wc -l` is `16` for me?

Comment: How could mine be so big, I have been doing a lot of docker-compose down and builds recently, so I'm not sure why it would grow?

Comment: Also that image launches sql server in the background so a `tail` is used as the main process in the container which is not good. Check the official [postgres](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/tree/3d0487a6caf77a2f0a66262158ff2719d1c22c94/10) or [mysql](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/tree/86431f073b3d2f963d21e33cb8943f0bdcdf143d/8.0) image entrypoints for how to init data and still run the database as the main process.

Comment: Thanks - any tips appreciated on that, I am pretty new to this, so I'm not sure what the tail is doing,

Comment: Possibly a dodgy build, try pulling it again?  `docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest`

Comment: You might be tagging your build as `microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest` too? So you keep adding layers onto the previous build.  Use `docker build -t me/mssql-server-linux .`

Comment: I'm just using `docker-compose build` should I be doing anything else? EDIT:  i went through a painful process and deleted every image (some wouldn't delete due to child images?) but I managed to force delete and re-pull everything and it works.  I'm worried how it got in this state in the first place?

Comment: Add your `docker-compose.yml` to the q. I think you've set the `image` to `microsoft/mssql-server-linux`

Comment: Your right I have! will post it - what should it be?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `image` parameter for a `service` in a `docker-compose.yml` definition has dual meanings depending on the existence of a `build` parameter.

- If there is no `build` stanza, The `image` will just be pulled and run.
- If you have a `build` stanza, `image` will be the name your built
  image is tagged as, and run.

By naming the built image `microsoft/mssql-server-linux`, which is the same as the `FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux` image. Docker was layering the build on top of itself each time.

The original build started on the "official" `microsoft/mssql-server-linux` but then each subsequent build would start from your local `microsoft/mssql-server-linux` image which had been appended to, until eventually you hit the maximum number of layers for your storage driver.

Use your own namespace for all images you build:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mssql:
      build: .
      image: 'user3437721/mssql-server-linux'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, still a lot of learning and this has helped immensely

Comment: It helps a lot!

Comment: That makes so much more sense now. I always wondered why I had to specify the image in both the docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile.

Answer (score 39):

Delete all local docker images related to your dockerfile using the following and try again.

```
$ docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
```

Comment: My soluction in this case on windows 10 pro using linux containers

Comment: Worked for me on Arch/Manjaro with Unix containers

Comment: This isn't actually a solution to the root problem, but it is a helpful command for cleaning up once you find yourself in this state.

Comment: Solved several issues for me which must have been solved from building and rebuilding over and over again. Clearing it all down reset things properly

Answer (score 16):

I was already using a custom image name like in the accepted answer, and I still had this issue.

In order to get past this error, I found that I needed to remove all unused (not associated with any container) and dangling (old image after a new one is made) docker images with the following command:

```bash
docker image prune -a
```

See https://linuxhandbook.com/remove-docker-images/

Answer (score 3):

If this error pops for specific images, then you might want to take a look at the number of layers that exist in your said docker image. When doing changes to a Docker image, each change is getting added as a layer regardless the size increase in the image. I have come across scenarios where my docker images having multiple layers and failing to push in Jenkins jobs. The workaround is to use the same context in the docker image but with reduced amount of layers. For that you can simply take out the content of the image and port them into a new image with a new image name, which will result the same content in a new image and with less amount of layers. Use this tip across scenarios that is helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same issue but could not get that resolved by renaming the image name in docker-compose.yml

I had to update my Dockerfile to reduce number of RUN commands

Replaced this

```
# Update php.ini
RUN echo 'memory_limit = -1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini;
RUN echo 'max_execution_time = 1800' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini;
RUN echo 'zlib.output_compression = On' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini;
RUN echo 'date.timezone = UTC' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini;
RUN echo 'upload_max_filesize = 100M' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini;
RUN echo 'post_max_size = 100M' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini;
RUN echo 'max_input_vars = 10000' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini;
RUN echo 'xdebug.mode = off' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini;
RUN echo 'xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini;
RUN echo 'realpath_cache_size = 10M' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini;
RUN echo 'realpath_cache_ttl = 7200' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini;
```

With this

```
# Update php.ini
RUN echo "memory_limit = -1; max_execution_time = 1800; zlib.output_compression = On; date.timezone = UTC; upload_max_filesize = 100M; max_input_vars = 10000; xdebug.mode = off; xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal; realpath_cache_size = 10M; realpath_cache_ttl = 7200" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini;
```

And it worked for me :) Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

for my situation the error was due to \r. I am running windows host and the linux image needs to run an script file for entrypoint which is copied from windows to docker image. during this process the script end lines were changed from \n to \r\n which resulted in this error. undoing this made the error go away.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the `image:` in docker-compose.yml with a unique custom name like "my-custom-prefix/..."

```
# docker-compose.yml
services:
    mssql:
        build: .
        image: my-custom-prefix/mssql-server-linux
...
```

Just making sure it is not the same as the `FROM` on top of your Dockerfile (build file)

```
# Dockerfile
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux
...
```

The same goes for a .lando.yml file. That was the case for me at least.